# Как на карту OSM вывести все маркеры из API? Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Я делаю вывод маркеров из АПИ на карту: для это создал массив с Маркерами и отдельный массив с остановками, из массива с остановками я forEach-ем вытаскиваю все координаты и складываю в массив со всеми маркерами и пытаюсь запустить все точки на карту.
Падение в ошибку пофикшено. спасибо за подсказку в комментариях.

Теперь проблема следующая (довольно глупая проблема, не понимаю. что оно не так работает):

Точки отображаются, но не там, где мне нужно. То есть мне нужно, чтобы точки координаты которых - Вологодская область, отображались именно в ней, а не в Казахстане :)

Ошибки в запросе быть не может, иначе бы не прилетал ответ от сервака в стэктрейс. Думаю, что как-то неправильно задаю саму карту, но я уж три часа ее кручу-верчу, но все никак не могу сообразить, что не так делаю. Сейчас код выглядит вот

```
  class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    futureStops = fetchStops();
    super.initState();
  }

  List<Stop> listStops = [];
  Future<List<Stop>> futureStops;
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Stop>>(
          future: futureStops,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              listStops = snapshot.data;
              print('xdecf');
              listStops.forEach((Stops) {
                print('bedcbjhefc');
                allMarkers = listStops
                    .map(
                      (e) => Marker(
                          width: 0.2,
                          height: 0.2,
                          point: latLong.LatLng(e.stLat, e.stLat),
                          builder: (_) => Icon(
                                Icons.person_pin,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              )),
                    )
                    .take(3)
                    .toList();
                print(allMarkers);
                print('object');
              });
            }
            return FlutterMap(
                options: MapOptions(
                  center: latLong.LatLng(координаты),
                  zoom: 13.0,
                ),
                layers: [
                  TileLayerOptions(
                      urlTemplate:
                          "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                  MarkerLayerOptions(markers: allMarkers),
                ]);
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает проверки на null

```
listStops!.forEach(
// либо
if(listStops != null) {
```

Comment: спасибо, в ошибку падать перестало, теперь пытаюсь понять, почему маркеры не отображаются на карте

Comment: Полученные из инета данные должны помещаться в стейт через seState https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту задачу: было странно, что не работало вчера, потому что вроде как все правильно сделал. Здесь оставляю ответ, на случай если кому-нибудь нужно будет готовое решение этой проблемы.

Задача стояла такая: использовать исключительно опенсорс и сверху сделать окно с дополнительной инфой про маркер (местоположение, название и т.д). Также всё то огромное количество точек, которое мне нужно вывести, было решено объединить в кластеры, потому что такое огромное количество точек карта бы проглотить не смогла.

Использовал вот эти пакеты и с такой версией sdk:

```
 sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

flutter_map_marker_popup: ^1.0.0
  flutter_map: ^0.14.0
  flutter_map_marker_cluster: ^0.4.0
  latlong2: ^0.8.1
```

У меня написано не на null-safety.

Поэтому для решения моей проблемы создал два массива: массив с маркерами и массив с моими точками/координатами, после этого использовал простой future builder (наверное есть способ элегантнее, но я сам до него не додумался) и два метода `forEach` и `map`. Чтобы они постоянно не валились в ошибку, проверяю, есть ли вообще что-нибудь внутри FutureBuilder.

```
class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {


  final PopupController _popupController = PopupController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureStops = fetchStops();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Stop>> futureStops;
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
  List<Stop> listStops = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Stop>>(
            future: fetchStops(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                listStops = snapshot.data;
                print('POINT 1');
                listStops.forEach((element) {
                  allMarkers = listStops
                      .map((e) =>
                      Marker(
                          point: latLong.LatLng(e.stLat, e.stLong),
                          builder: (_) => Icon(Icons.person_pin)))
                      .toList(growable: true);
                });
              }
              return FlutterMap(
                options: new MapOptions(
                  center: latLong.LatLng(ваши координаты),
                  zoom: 13,
                  plugins: [
                    MarkerClusterPlugin(),
                  ],

                  //HERE IS ON TAP OPTIONS
                ),
                layers: [
                  TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                  ),
                  MarkerClusterLayerOptions(
                    maxClusterRadius: 120,
                    size: Size(40, 40),
                    markers: allMarkers,
                    polygonOptions: PolygonOptions(
                        borderColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        color: Colors.black12,
                        borderStrokeWidth: 3),
                    popupOptions: PopupOptions(
                      popupSnap: PopupSnap.mapTop,
                      popupController: _popupController,
                      popupBuilder: (_, allMarkers) => Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => debugPrint('on marker tapped'),
                          child: Text('Container popup for marker at ${allMarkers.point}'),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
                    builder: (context, markers) {
                      return FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Text(markers.length.toString()),
                        onPressed: null,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
        ));
  }
}
```

Может способ и не самый эффективный с точки зрения производительности (карта загрузилась за 3 секунды, прорисовав потом все кластеры почти моментально, то есть ну секунд 5-7 на это все дело ушло), но рабочий. Опять-таки повторюсь, что сам пока не додумался как сделать лучше. Тут оставляю ответ на случай, если кому-нибудь понадобится когда-то :)